# Is it possible to transfer files in uboot using RARP?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, dhcp, tftp

I have an embedded board in which I want download the rootfs, kernel etc in uboot.
It does not have tftp.
Can I use RARP for transferring files?

I have tried this:

1. I have installed rarp server on host.(apt-get rarpd)
2. Created an /etc/ethers file, listing the client's MAC ID like this:
   08:ed:ed:25:4f:0e   client
3. Added the client to the /etc/hosts file like this:
   192.168.16.20.220 client
4. Ran the command rarpd -A
5. On the client side, in the uboot prompt, I run this "
   rarpboot 0x82000000 192.168.16.77:test_file"
   (/rarpboot folder is created with the required permission).

But I am unable to download any file from rarpboot.

If it is not possible to transfer files using RARP, is there any other way other than tftp ?
suggest other options if available ..!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I booted one of PPC440 boards like this.

Comment: Can you please explain the method you followed for this?  Is my method explained having any mistakes ?

Comment: An alternative is booting via UEFI and iPXE. See https://www.xypron.de/projects/u-boot/iscsi.html